# Why is "missing" added to waiting in Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, tiempo

In Perú we say "me falta esperar 10 minutos", in United States we do not say "I am missing waiting 10 minutes". Why is "falta/missing" added in Peruvian Spanish? Or conversely, why in American English do we not say we lost our time?

Or am I translating that badly and the Spanish speaker is saying something more like "I lost 10 minutes waiting for the bus"?

Comment: I would understand it as, "I have 10 minutes **left** to wait."

Comment: @jrdioko you might want to post it as an answer, as it is the actual meaning indeed.

Answer (score 5):

In this sense, *faltar* means "to be left." So "me falta esperar 10 minutos" would be translated "I have 10 minutes **left** to wait." If you were talking about losing time you'd use *perder*.

Answer (score 1):

The expression *`me falta esperar 10 minutos`* is not customary from any particular country, it is standard spanish.
You could also say *`Me faltan 10 minutos de espera`*  or *`Me quedan 10 minutos de espera`*.
Its literal meaning is *`I have 10 minutes of waiting left`*, which would be said more commonly by an english speaker as *`I still have to wait 10 more minutes`*.

Another example:
*`It's 10 minutes left for the arrival`* ==> *`Quedan/Faltan 10 minutos para la llegada`*